# How to assign a value to bootstrap tooltip's title attribute using string interpolation in angular?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, html-title

I want title attribute's value to be dynamic. However it works fine when `title="Hello!!"` is used, but when I use `title="{{mystring}}"` it works, but shows default `HTML` style tooltip not, Bootstrap style `tooltip`.

Comment: What element are you adding the `title=""` to?

Comment: I tried with a button and a div